# How to generate an external library to work in the ROS as the thirdparty file?

Tags: ros, library, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all:
Today, I generated an external library using Eclipse, but I want to make it working as the thirdparty file, which is similar as gvars or libvcd in the ethzal_ptam package, but I did not have the file like configure file in them! How to do it?
Thanks!!

BTW: the whole process is below steps:
1. I generate an empty Shared Library project, and then write my class files(.h and .cpp, no main function), after compiled it, I got my library .so!
2. I copy the whole files(include the library) to the thirdparty in the ethzal_ptam, and copy the makefile from the gvars3, modify it similarly, it seems the Eclipse has make it successful, but when I use the function in that library, it could not work, how could I solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49159/how-to-generate-an-external-library-to-work-in-the-ros-as-the-thirdparty-file?/) by [Wolf_Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2044/wolf_wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a wiki entry that describes [how to use third party libraries](http://www.ros.org/wiki/UsingThirdPartyLibraries).

However, I'm not sure what you want to do from your description. If you are actually writing the library code yourself, you could just make it a ROS library (unless you'd like it standalone of course, then wrap it as described above).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2